# Vue warning during test execution

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm building a Vue application starting from the webpack template ([vue-wepack-template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack)).
During the execution of unit test through the command:

```
yarn run unit
```

I can see some Vue warnings:

```
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* /Users/xxxxxxx/components/node_modules/vue-loader/index.js??ref--1!/Users/xxxxxxxx/components/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--0!/Users/xxxxxxxx/components/src/components/Layout/FullScreen.vue
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.

ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-link> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3"
```

They looks like some kind of Webpack configuration problem, but I don't know where to start to debug this. I haven't touched the default test configuration and the test are running fine...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like multiple problems.

**1. Unknown custom element:**

You don't have vue-router installed on the Vue instance. vue-router adds a global component - router-link - which one of the components you're rendering is looking for.

**Solution**

You can install vue-router before your tests:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter) // install vue-router
```

Or register a mock router-link component to your vue instance

```
Vue.component('router-link', { // registers router-link component
  template: `<div />`
})
```

Before running your tests

**2. There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.**

This error is often thrown when you accidentally capitalize a module import:

```
// some-file.js
import vue from 'vue'
// another-file.js
import vue from 'Vue' // Cause of error - multiple modules with names that only differ in casing
```

**Solution**

Make sure you use lowercase to identify modules in import:

```
// some-file.js
import vue from 'vue'
// another-file.js
import vue from 'Vue'
```

In your case, it looks like the error occurs when you import `Layout/FullScreen.vue`

**3. Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3"**

This looks like an error in one of your Vue modules.

Somewhere you are referencing d3, but it has not been imported.

**solution**

Make sure d3 is imported.

*Note:* I could be wrong, and this could be a problem with webpack. Try to debug with these solutions, and if you can't fix the errors open an issue in [vue-webpack-template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).